# PHP extracting without extract()

Tags: php, extract

I have something like:

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $linktitle=strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$title));
```

etc.

`$linktitle` and `$title` are actually variables from `$_POST` - ie `$_POST['linktitle']` and `$_POST['title']`. 
Somehow, even though (as far as I can see!) I haven't extract()ed $_POST at this stage in the code, it is still working - PHP is understanding that $title is referring to `$_POST['title']`. Could anyone please explain why this might be?

Thanks!

ps. Sorry, but I really can't get this inline code quote formatting thing to work...!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) is enabled in your PHP instance. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) for more info.

This is behaviour that should be relied upon as it's use is now deprecated. You will find that you can still use `$_POST['keyname']` as well as `$keyname`, and that is what you should refer to in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your php.ini file must have `register_globals` enabled, so GPC variables are being added to the symbol table. This is why you see this behaviour. See the security risks of such a feature [here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)

Answer (score 1):

You have [register globals](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) activated in your webserver (php.ini), so PHP replace the unknoe variables with the corresponding GET or POST value. This option is deprecated and dangerous! Disable it if you can!